# better expression for telling about your uncertain schedule

Tags: expression-choice, phrase-requests, email

I am responding to an email where another person is asking about when I will be available next week?.
Now, I am not yet sure about my next week schedule. It depends on couple of important must-have meetings which are not scheduled yet. I wrote following response:

> Right now, I am not certain about my next week schedule. It depends on couple of must-to-attend but yet-unscheduled meetings.
>   I will send you a follow-up email by end of this week about my availability.

Can you please suggest some better way to describe it?

Comment: "I have a few commitments next week that don't have firm times yet - I am eager to meet next week but I' wont know my exact availablity until Sunday or Monday" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It describes the situation in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say something like:

> My schedule next week is still up in the air and contingent on
>   meetings that are to be determined.  I will keep you informed as the
>   situation develops.

Comment: using the KISS principal: My schedule next week is uncertain. I shall let you know by weeks end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a final schedule yet  for next week as it depends on the confirmation of some important meetings, but I will update you of my availability once I got them confirmed.

Hope this helps.